# Interpretation of an interval involving composite functions

Tags: calculus

We know that $\int f(x)dx$ represents the area of a curve where $x$ is an independent variable varying over all real numbers.But what does $\int h(g(x)) dg(x)$ represent?I see people using change of variables formula in integration and that boils down to like $\int z dz=\frac{z^2}{2}+c$ where we are usingthe properties proved for ordinary integration where x was an independent varible but here $z$ is a function of $x$.Could you please shed some light on what does the integral $\int h(g(x)) dg(x)$ mean?

Comment: There's a 3D geometric interpretation of that in this question , if that is what you are looking for : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388158/what-is-the-geometrical-meaning-of-a-riemann-stieltjes-integral#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20geometrical%20meaning%20of%20a%20Riemann%2DStieltjes%20integral%3F,-riemann%2Dintegration&text=Geometrical%20meaning%20of%20Reimann%20integration,Riemann%20integration%20are%20easily%20understandable.

Comment: just call $g(x)$ , $t$ , then it is no brainer.

Comment: I don't understand,could you be a bit more elaborate jimjim

Comment: Teresa Lisbon My question was regarding $h(g(x))$ with respect to $g(x)$ but the link you gave shows $f(x)$ with respect to $g(x)$.

Comment: just write it like that, what do you get